# Views - how to pass number field to javascript?

Tags: views

I need to create settings javascripts with data from views row. So I used views_php module and created next view field structure:

- Taxonomy term: Name (string, hidden)
- Taxonomy term: Max price (numerical, formatting turned off, hidden)
- Taxonomy term: Min price (numerical, formatting turned off, hidden)
- PHP field

In PHP I used next :

```
drupal_add_js(array(
  'term' => array(
    'name' => $row->name,
    'max_price' => $row->field_min_price,
    'min_price' => $row->field_max_price,
  )
), 'settings');
```

But, e.g. for next values :
- Name: 'test term'
- Min price: 0
- Max price: 1000
I getting next JS:

```
{
  name: 'test term',
  min_price: 1,
  max_price: 1,
}
```

Both of `min_price` and `max_price` fields contains 1. Also, when I showing this fields at view - I can see correct values in rendered HTML, but not in JS.

Comment: Also, as a workeraund I used `'term' => taxonomy_term_load($row->tid)`.